# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'assert_hostname'

Tags: python-2.7, flask

I am getting this error when invoking a restful api service. I am getting a starnge error "TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'assert_hostname'" while invoking the service. Could you please help me to figure out what could be the reason for the error.

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__

return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app

response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception

reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app

response = self.full_dispatch_request()

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request

rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception

reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request

rv = self.dispatch_request()

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request

return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_login.py", line 758, in decorated_view

return func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/var/www/vwtools/app/toolset/views.py", line 33, in decorated

return func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/var/www/vwtools/app/toolset/views.py", line 101, in invoke_model_api

mr = api.create_modelrun( modelrun=dict(title='Model Run-Toolset', model_name='prms'))

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/client/swagger_client/apis/default_api.py", line 119, in create_modelrun

callback=params.get('callback'))

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/client/swagger_client/api_client.py", line 322, in call_api

response_type, auth_settings, callback)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/client/swagger_client/api_client.py", line 149, in __call_api

post_params=post_params, body=body)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/client/swagger_client/api_client.py", line 358, in request

body=body)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/client/swagger_client/rest.py", line 213, in POST

body=body)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/client/swagger_client/rest.py", line 147, in request

headers=headers)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 73, in request

**urlopen_kw)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 151, in request_encode_body

return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 248, in urlopen

response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 583, in urlopen

conn = self._get_conn(timeout=pool_timeout)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 257, in _get_conn

return conn or self._new_conn()

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 218, in _new_conn

strict=self.strict, **self.conn_kw)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 126, in __init__

_HTTPConnection.__init__(self, *args, **kw)

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'assert_hostname'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The api client was not able to understand the api url given. After makig a host entry for the api domain in the residing api containers hosts file. the issue is resolved